# Does dispatching on a Boost variant type take linear time?

Tags: c++, boost, variant

How efficient is dispatching on a boost::variant ?

If it's a switch statement, it should only take O(1) time, but as far as I know, template metaprogrammign can only generate if's, which would put boost::variant dispatchs at a runtime overhead of O(n), where n = number of types in the variant.

Can anyone confirm/deny/enlighten me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source, it should be constant time. Boost uses Boost.PreProcessor to generate a switch-table, and keeps track of which index it should jump to (via the type being stored).

Comment: Which is EXACTLY what I suggested the last TWO times he asked this question TODAY.

Answer (score 0):

> but as far as I know, template metaprogrammign can only generate if's, which would put boost::variant dispatchs at a runtime overhead of O(n),

No: template metaprogramming `if`s are evaluated *at compile time* so if the overhead is defined by template metaprogramming, it will be a *compile time overhead*. Runtime overhead will then be constant.

Caveat: I do not know how `boost::variant` dispatch works. But *if* it’s implemented using compile-time `if`, it will behave as described above.

Comment: +1. Also, a code generator can very well turn nested or chained `if` s testing the same var against a succession of values into a `switch`. This is the kind of thing you don't worry about until you verify it's happening wrong.